# Ajax change field of parent form depending on nested form Cocoon Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cocoon-gem

Sorry for the messed up title but I don't even know how to explain my problem correctly..

I have rails app with a Reservation form which has a field "total_price".
The form can add/remove Rooms via 
 **cocoon gem**
   https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon (ajax)  room model has a  field "price".

How can I update the field total_price depending on how many rooms and what type they have selected ?

reservations/new_html.erb

```
   <%= simple_form_for @reservation do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
<fieldset>
  <%= f.input :date_from, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'date', id: 'checkin',  :placeholder   => 'From' }, :label => false %>

  <%= f.input :date_to, as: :string, input_html: { class: 'date', id: 'checkout', :label => false %>

  <div id="rooms">
    <%= f.fields_for :entries do |entry| %>
        <%= render 'entry_fields', :f => entry %>
    <% end %>

    <%=  link_to_add_association 'add room', f, :entries %>
  </div>

  <%= f.input :total_price, :label => false %>
</fieldset>

<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

reservations/_entry_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.association :rooms, input_html: { class: 'room-select' },  :label => false %>
    <%= f.number_field :number_of_rooms, input_html: { class: 'room-count' }, :label => false %>
    <%=  link_to_remove_association "Remove room", f %>
  </div>
</div>
```

ReservationsController

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @reservation = Reservation.new
    end
    def create
     @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
     if @reservation.save

      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Booking Confirmed"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
    def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:date_to, :date_from,  entries_attributes: [ :reservation_id, :number_of_rooms, :_destroy, :room_ids => []])
  end
end
```

my apps/assets/javascript/application.js is empty except including jquery and cocoon

Cocoon does support callbacks but my very limited JS knowledge just cannot come up with a solution.

**Any guidance would be greatly appriciated,**
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, afaik the total-price does not change when you add a new room, it changes when you select the room or the number of rooms (I am assuming that selecting a room actually selects a type).

So you can use simple jquery for that.

And when you dynamically remove a room, then the total price changes, and you should use the `cocoon:after_remove` callback for that.

Recap:

- when `.room-select` or `.room-count` receives a `change` event --> recalculate total price
- when `cocoon:after-remove` event is triggered --> recalculate total price